# How do I set up Google Analytics Event Tracking for Goals?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I got the site tracking code from

https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/?authuser=1#management/Settings/

Which looks like

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-9999999"></script>
  ...
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-99999999999');
```

This page uses the function `ga` which doesn't appear to exist.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

This page mentions Google Tag Manager

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136960/?hl=en&authuser=1

But the code from Google Tag Manager is completely different, with different account numbers. It has 2 code snippets, and looks like

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
...
```

And

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXX
```

I tried to follow the docs at

https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106716#FormSubmit

But the following fields did not exist.

> Category: Forms 
>   Action: Submit 
>   Label: Lead Gen - {{Form ID}}

I tested a form submission, but it didn't appear to send any form event to Google Analytics.  Also, I don't see how to link the event to the goal defined in Google Analytics.

https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/?authuser=1#management/Settings

The goal detail has 'action' equal to 'register', but there was absolutely nothing in Google Tag Manager allowing me to define a Category, Action, Label, or Value.

Comment: Google changed the recommendation for code integration to gtag.js and made a pigs ear out of it. Documentation for event tracking with gtag.js is here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events. If you use gtag.js you should not be looking at the documentation for analytics.js (that's the previous code version), that will just confuse you.

Comment: I have not played with gtag() a whole ton yet, but my understanding is that the gtag library also loads analytics.js so the functionality may still be there (and *maybe* even the ga() function itself). This is something I want to look into more myself, but thought I'd mention it as food for thought.